# python3.5/pandas - converting multiple columns into datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

So I am trying to convert 2 columns into 1 datetime column. Input columns look like this:

```
date            hour
1/1/2015          1
1/1/2015          2
1/1/2015          3
```

where the values of `df.date` is a `string` and the values of `df.hour` is an `int`. I am trying to convert these two columns into one such that:

```
datetime
2015-1-1 1:00:00
2015-1-1 2:00:00
2015-1-1 3:00:00
```

I thought a simple `df['x'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['date', 'hour']]` would work but I'm getting a `ValueError` as a result

Comment: Is the frequency is always 1 hour?

Comment: @JoeR yes,frequency is always at 1 hour intervals. Sorry, forgot to clarify that.

Comment: @JoeR. Well, sometimes there could be a lapse from the observations that's why I wanted to convert it from the 2 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can paste the two columns together as a single column and then convert with a corresponding `format` parameter:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['hour'].astype(str), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H")

# 0   2015-01-01 01:00:00
# 1   2015-01-01 02:00:00
# 2   2015-01-01 03:00:00
# dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Woah, Thanks! solution seems simple. Never thought `to_datetime` will work like that. I got an error with my original data but it worked with some simple data I tested out. I'll just look at my original data first. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you will need to use [`pandas.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`datetime.timedelta`](https://pymotw.com/2/datetime/).

```
from datetime import timedelta
df = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + df['hour'].apply(lambda x: timedelta(hours=int(x)))
```

**Explanation:**

```
from datetime import timedelta
dft['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dft['date'])
dft['hour_h'] = dft['hour'].apply(lambda x: timedelta(hours=int(x)))
dff = dft['date']+dft['hour_h']
```

**Output:**

```
dff
Out[42]: 
0   2015-01-01 01:00:00
1   2015-01-01 02:00:00
2   2015-01-01 03:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: @kobrakai, You are welcome. Hope it helps, `datetime` is indedd a powerful package for dealing with all the datetime problems regardless if your are using `pandas` or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach:

```
In [224]:
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['hour'], unit='h')
df

Out[224]:
       date  hour            datetime
0  1/1/2015     1 2015-01-01 01:00:00
1  1/1/2015     2 2015-01-01 02:00:00
2  1/1/2015     3 2015-01-01 03:00:00
```

basically the key difference here is to construct a `TimedeltaIndex` from the hour column and add this to the converted `datetime` col result from `to_datetime`